# 500 Internal Server Error For these Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
```

These two lines are the problem

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

...

```
 RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php

 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know why this is an internal server error and how to fix it, I have one rule that prevents users from accessing the non https version, and another that does some rewriting the url and redirecting. I use a controller to handle all the webpages.

Comment: i would start by removing them all and adding them back one at a time until i found the problem

Comment: I found it, it's either the first rewriteCond or rule. The ones that change the https. Not sure what is wrong with it though, I tried fixing all the new lines.

Comment: Use `REQUEST_FILENAME` instead of `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

Comment: The way I have the site set up, the index file pulls the proper page based on the url, so it's really a controller that always loads no matter where you are on the site

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Main changes are to your `https` detection as well as using `REQUEST_FILENAME` instead of `SCRIPT_FILENAME`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on 
  ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

  RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  

  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also a good debugging technique for something like this is to use `curl -I` from the command line if you are in Unix/Linux or Mac OS X. That will return header information including redirects & such. For example, here is the `curl -I` output for Google on `http://google.com/`:

```
curl -I http://google.com/

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 23:20:00 GMT
Expires: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 23:20:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

Note the `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` and `Location: http://www.google.com/` lines. That tells you that Google’s servers are set to redirect `google.com` requests to `www.google.com`. Using this on your own local rules is a great way to debug when compared to loading a URL in browser & dealing with cached content issues.

**EDIT:** Since in your comments you explain how everything is going through `index.php`, try using this slightly modified version of the default WordPress `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So I no longer have the 500 error, but when I try and load the http instead of the https, instead of redirecting to https, it gets rid of all the forward slashes in the url

Comment: An example "http://google.com/hi" becomes "https://google.comhi", first being http and the latter being https

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've gotten it down to one issue, "http://google.com/hi?tags=blah" becomes "https://google.comhi/?tags=blah", first being http and the latter being https

Comment: I did try the wordpress htaccess, and there is no 500 error, but the same problem persists. I'm not sure why it's moving the slash to the other side of the word for non https, https work perfectly though

Comment: no luck. I am unsure why it is swapping the / from one side to the other

Comment: Fixed it. Just had to move the https lines to the top above everything